# Cant seem to find the Syntax error

Tags: data-warehouse

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong here, I am getting incorrect syntax near where. Whats wrong with the statement?

```
INSERT INTO dbo.a1
    select x1 as id, x2 as enc_id, x3 as dev,x4 as mang, x4 as sre, x5 as phase,x6, x7, x8
    from
    (select *,
    row_number() over(partition by x2 order by x8)  as rank
    from ccsm.n9 where xx=1 and xx_pat=1 and xx_encz='Tesz')
     where rank=1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never told us what version of SQL you are using, but one possibility is that your derived table needs an alias:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.a1
SELECT t.x1, t.x2, t.x3, t.x4, t.x4, t.x5, t.x6, t.x7, t.x8
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY x2 ORDER BY x8) AS rank
    FROM ccsm.n9
    WHERE xx = 1 and xx_pat = 1 and xx_encz = 'Tesz'
) t
WHERE t.rank = 1;
```

I know that Oracle enforces the derived table alias rule, and possibly other databases as well.  Note that the aliases you had in the `SELECT` statement serve no purpose because the values are just being inserted.  If you wish to insert `x4` twice then just repeat it twice.

Comment: Am running this in azure datawarehouse

Comment: Let us know if this answer helped you.

Comment: Can you provide me some documentation where I can learn using alias and derived tables concept.

Comment: Your answer surely helped, but if I dont use t in select statement would it serve the purpose of the query?

Comment: You might be able to not use the alias `t` in the outer `SELECT` and `WHERE` clauses, but it certainly should not be wrong to do so.